# I can't seem to use npm, git and node on my system

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, npm

I'm running a Windows 10 machine. I have tried to install node and git but whenever I try using git or npm it just return the user pointer back.

```
WindowsPC MINGW64 /c/Angular
$ git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart my-app
Cloning into 'my-app'...

WindowsPC MINGW64 /c/Angular
```

that is what happen when i use git. it did not create the folder `my-app`

and if am using the cmd

```
C:\Users\Username>npm -v

C:\Users\Username>
```

Nothing seems to work 
however if i try to check node-v it works fine.

```
C:\Users\Username>node -v
v6.10.0

C:\Users\Username>
```

so do any one what could be the cause of this?

Because I can't learn angular 2 because of this

Comment: That git clone looks like it worked. Did it not create a my-app folder?

Comment: no @slebetman it did not create the folder

Comment: Is there a `sh.exe.stackdump` file in your current folder after executing that `git` command? If so then post its contents.

Comment: Also, try `which git` and `which npm`

Comment: no there was no `sh.exe.stackdump` `git version 2.8.1.windows.1`

Answer (score 0):

As `git clone` didn't report any error it seems it was successful.
So just do `cd my-app` after the `git clone` and you should be inside your newly cloned repository.

Comment: it didn't return any folder it was empty

Comment: What is "it", what do you mean by "return" and what was empty?

Comment: the `my-app` folder it was empty

Comment: Do you maybe not have write permissions in `/c/Angular`?

Comment: I do have write permission and i did the sane thing on my desktop. the same thing happen. I have installed a new version of node.js and it is still the same

Comment: Do you maybe need some proxy configuration and cannot access github.com directly?

Comment: What does `GIT_TRACE=1 git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart my-app` output?

Comment: `15:52:14.970453 git.c:351               trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'https://github.com/angular/quickstart' 'my-app'
Cloning into 'my-app'...
15:52:15.260447 run-command.c:336       trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://github.com/angular/quickstart'`
that is what is return and the folder is still empty. it did not create the `my-app` folder at all. No I dont need proxy cause i use composer freely without proxy

Comment: And my other question?

Answer (score 0):

and if you just

```
md my-proj
cd my-proj
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git
```

files are there ?

Comment: not at all. you should just have installed nodejs including npm